# Native Debian X32 Virtual Machine?

Tags: linux, installation, debian, x32

I'm trying to setup a native Debian X32 virtual machine. Note that X32 is different than X86 and X64. For details, see [Difference between x86, x32, and x64 architectures?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7635013) on Stack Overflow. Some other distros, like Red Hat, offer a X32 build for servers.

Debian does not provide an X32 ISO. I have Debian 8.2 amd64 installed, and the kernel is booting into the 32-bit configuration:

```
$ dmesg | grep -i x32
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-4-amd64 root=UUID=69773d98-b9fa-4695-8392-92759d8e6094 ro syscall.x32=y syscall.x32=y quiet
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-4-amd64 root=UUID=69773d98-b9fa-4695-8392-92759d8e6094 ro syscall.x32=y syscall.x32=y quiet
[    0.316500] Enabled x32 syscalls
```

Debian's [X32-port wiki](http://wiki.debian.org/X32Port) tells me the next step is to setup a QEMU chroot. I want to avoid the QEMU chroot and turn this into a native X32 installation.

***Question***: How do I turn this installation into a native X32 installation?

---

Though I am booting the kernel configured for X32, the userland tools are *not* configured that way. For example, the compiler is probably most important to me, but its not configured for X32:

```
$ g++ -march=native -dM -E - </dev/null | egrep "(x86_64|amd64|ilp)"
#define __x86_64 1
#define __amd64 1
#define __x86_64__ 1
#define __amd64__ 1
```

I don't see `ILP32` or `__ILP32__`, which I means I'm not in X32 mode. Changing `-march=native` to `-mx32` makes no difference.

---

Here is the machine:

```
$ uname -a
Linux debian8-x32q 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt20-1+deb8u3 (2016-01-17) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Here is my ***`sources.list`***. But its not obvious what I should enable to get the X32 binaries rather than the X64 binaries:

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie main
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie main

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main

# jessie-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main
```

---

The following works:

```
$ sudo dpkg --add-architecture x32
```

But it breaks APT:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Ign http://ftp.us.debian.org jessie InRelease
Hit http://ftp.us.debian.org jessie-updates InRelease 
Hit http://ftp.us.debian.org jessie Release.gpg                        
Hit http://ftp.us.debian.org jessie Release                            
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease              
Hit http://ftp.us.debian.org jessie-updates/main Sources             
Get:1 http://ftp.us.debian.org jessie-updates/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex [367 B]
Get:2 http://ftp.us.debian.org jessie/main Sources [7,058 kB]
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main Sources
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages     
Hit http://ftp.us.debian.org jessie/main amd64 Packages 
Fetched 7,058 kB in 3s (2,066 kB/s)          
W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/jessie/updates/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-x32/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-x32/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-x32/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

---

If it matters, I SSH into the box. I don't care about window managers and other GUI programs that have not been ported. I basically need the kernel, base installation and build tools to be in X32 mode so I can test my software under X32.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X32_ABI leaving this link here since I got confused. https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/pkgreport.cgi?users=debian-x32@lists.debian.org;tag=di-x32 seems to suggest that some of the things you need to directly run x32 might not be supported yet, like a bootloader.

Comment: Thanks Journeyman. *"x32 might not be supported yet, like a bootloader..."* - OK, thanks. I'm not sure if this is a problem in practice because we can boot the kernel with ***`syscall.x32=y`***. I've found its userland that is causing the pain, like the compiler.